# How to import package if the code is not hosted on internet

Tags: go, import, dockerfile

I have a package structure

```
$GOPATH/src/io.sure/api/proto/vi/party.pb.go
        .../io.sure/party/party.go
        ../io.sure/Dockerfile
```

import of party.go are

```
import (  
    "context"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "io.sure/api/proto/v1"
    "log"
    "net"
)
```

```
FROM golang:1.12.1-alpine AS builder   
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git   
WORKDIR /go/src/app  
COPY ./party/ .  
COPY ./api/ .  
RUN go get -d -v  
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go install

FROM scratch  
WORKDIR /opt  
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/app .  
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/app"]
```

The code compiles and runs from a command line. But when I build a docker image, go get tries to download io.sure/api/proto/v1 even when i have a copied the api folder in the docker image. How can i stop/skip downloading the package, as I do not have the code on github or any other public repo.

Is vendoring a right thing to do, since its my own package which may not be exported or exported to outside world.

I tried go modules but i am facing issues and still want to work with GOPATH.

---

ried both the combinations but still the same error. code does get copied in image gopath.

FROM golang:1.12.1-alpine AS builder
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/io.sure
COPY ./party/ .
COPY ./api/ .
RUN go get -d -v
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go install

FROM scratch
WORKDIR /opt
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/app .
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/app"]

FROM golang:1.12.1-alpine AS builder
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src
RUN mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/io.sure
COPY ./party/ .
COPY ./api/ .
RUN go get -d -v
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go install

FROM scratch
WORKDIR /opt
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/app .
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/app"]
Fetching https://io.sure/api/proto/v1/party?go-get=1 https fetch failed: Get https://io.sure/api/proto/v1/party?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup io.sure on xxx.xx.0.2:53: no such host package io.sure/api/proto/v1/party: unrecognized import path "io.sure/api/proto/v1/party" (https fetch: Get https://io.sure/api/proto/v1/party?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup io.sure on xxx.31.0.2:53: no such host)

Comment: Are you sure that you are copying host gopath into the image gopath directory?

Comment: The code does get copied as go get tires to get io.sure from internet.

Answer (score 2):

The content of your `$GOPATH` differs between cli and Dockerimage in that your packages are not in the right place.

You need to `RUN mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/io.sure` and `COPY ./party $GOPATH/src/io.sure/` to achieve the same layout in the Dockerimage like on the cli.

You probably need to adapt the Paths but I hope you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

found the solution. modified Dockerfile. All dependencies are managed with Godep

changed workdir to /go/src/github.com/kubesure/party

added RUN echo "[url \"git@github.com:\"]\n\tinsteadOf = https://github.com/" >>

---

```
RUN echo "[url \"git@github.com:\"]\n\tinsteadOf = https://github.com/" >> /root/.gitconfig
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/kubesure/party
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go install

FROM scratch
WORKDIR /opt
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/party .
EXPOSE 50051
CMD ["/opt/party"]
```